# How to use ndgrid with interp2

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Matlab infamously has two functions for creating gridded data, `ndgrid` and `meshgrid`. `meshgrid` is very annoying because it mixes up rows and columns whereas `ndgrid` keeps it consistent. So I like to stick with `ndgrid`.

But it turns out, in order to interpolate using `interp2`, I need `meshgrid` style gridded data. But the rest of my code cannot handle if I used `meshgrid`, I want to stick to `ndgrid`. How do I make `ndgrid` work with `interp2`, and what is the method to this madness? I am sick of randomly transposing matrices until the code works.

```
[X, Y]=ndgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:2);
F=cos(X).*sin(Y);
[X2, Y2]=ndgrid(0:0.05:1,0:0.05:2);
F2=interp2(X,Y,F,X2,Y2);
```

I know there is a way to get this to work by transposing bunch of stuff, what is the right way to do this? It is so immensely confusing when `ndgrid` and `meshgrid` are flipping rows and columns around, there has to be a "right way" to navigate this. Over the course of past six years, I have been brought to tears by the frustration caused by `ndgrid` and `meshgrid` flipping around rows and columns.

Comment: There are [reasons](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99720) for both `meshgrid` and `ndgrid` to exist, but I feel your pain. Have you looked into the newer (since R2011b) [`griddedIntepolant`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html) for your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`griddedIntepolant`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddedinterpolant.html), which makes `ndgrid`-like assumptions. For your example:

```
[X, Y]=ndgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:2);
Z=cos(X).*sin(Y);
F=griddedInterpolant(X, Y, Z);
[X2, Y2]=ndgrid(0:0.05:1,0:0.05:2);
Z2=F(X2,Y2);
```

If you need to use `interp2` for 2-D cases like your example, then it suffices to know that `[X, Y]=ndgrid(x,y)` is equivalent to `[Y, X]=meshgrid(y,x)`. So for your example, you could do:

```
[X, Y]=ndgrid(0:0.1:1,0:0.1:2);
F=cos(X).*sin(Y);
[X2, Y2]=ndgrid(0:0.05:1,0:0.05:2);
F2=interp2(Y,X,F,Y2,X2);
```

Lastly, [this is supposedly the general method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html#mw_71269e7a-84d4-4223-b48a-fa49cc5d8e43) to covert from `meshgrid` to `ndgrid` in 3-D.

Comment: I wish there was a way to tell matlab "this is a sampled scalar field, NOT A MATRIX. dont get it twisted!"