# How can I slice NIFTI image in desired point with reference plane?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, nifti, mri

Hi I am new to NIFTI data,

Imagine I have a reference plane, In any voxel point I want to make a slice of specific weighted amount. So my slice should align with my reference plane as it should look like my plane translated on that specific voxel position.

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection

def rotate_plane_around_point(reference_plane_points, rotation_vector, voxel_coordinates, image_path):
    img = nib.load(image_path)
    aff_matrix = img.affine[:3, :3]
    reference_plane_voxel = np.array(reference_plane_points)
    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_rotvec(rotation_vector).as_matrix()
    rotated_plane_voxel = np.dot(rotation_matrix, reference_plane_voxel.T).T
    real_world_coordinates = np.dot(aff_matrix, voxel_coordinates)
    rotated_plane_real_world = np.dot(aff_matrix, rotated_plane_voxel.T).T
    return real_world_coordinates, rotated_plane_real_world


image_path = 'brain_ct.nii'
voxel_coordinates = np.array([-12, -8, 12]) 
reference_plane_points = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]])
rotation_vector = np.radians([2.4, 0, 0])

real_world_coordinates, rotated_plane_real_world = rotate_plane_around_point(reference_plane_points, rotation_vector, voxel_coordinates, image_path)
```

`Here I got the point in my data to be rotated as my reference plane, but I don't have any idea of how to get the plane.`

Comment: Do you want to sllice a nifti volume along a plane with an arbitrary orientation, like [this](https://www.geogebra.org/m/nbbfnngc)? That requires more than computing the coordinates on the slice, because you need to interpolate the original volume to get the values in that slice. A matlab example for doing that is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76375233/1793968). Is this what you are after?

Comment: Yes, my plan is to have a reference plane that can be translated, rotated and interpolated to any plane in the image and get a slice along that plane.

Comment: then you probably need something like [this](https://discourse.slicer.org/t/rotating-and-resampling-volumes-with-python/9089)